# WordPress: get list of all custom post pages and add pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type, shortcode

I have a code that gets all thumbnails from custom post type named 'pavideo' and works as a shortcode:

```
// Shortcode to get thumbnails of all videos and create pagination
function pavideo_get_thumbnails_and_pagination(){
   ob_start();
   $content = '';
   $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'pavideo', 'orderby' => 'desc', 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) );
   while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
   // Check if post has thumbnail first
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       echo '<div class="other-video-block">
           <a href="';
           the_permalink();
           echo '" title="';
           the_title();
           echo '">';
           echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
           echo '</a><br>';
    echo '</div>';
} 
endwhile;
   $content = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   return $content;
}

// Define thumbnail and pagination shortcode
add_shortcode('pavideo_thumb','pavideo_get_thumbnails_and_pagination');
```

I need to get 4 thumbnails, and than create a pagination thing like: 1,2,3 and so on.

How could I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it! :)

I used wp-pagenavi plugin to display pagination like 1,2,3 and so on. My code now looks like that:

```
// Shortcode to get thumbnails of all videos and create pagination
function pavideo_get_thumbnails_and_pagination(){
   ob_start();

   $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

   $content = '';

   // The query
   $query = new WP_Query('post_type=pavideo&order=desc&posts_per_page=3&paged='.$paged);

   echo '<div class="pavideo-hp-videos">';

   while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
   // Check if post has thumbnail first
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       echo '<div class="pavideo-hp-single-video">
           <a href="';
           the_permalink();
           echo '" title="';
           the_title();
           echo '">';
           echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
           echo '</a>';
       echo '</div>';
   } 
   endwhile;

   echo '</div>';

   echo '<div class="pavideo-pagination">';
   wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );
   echo '</div>';

   $content = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   return $content;
}

// Define thumbnail and pagination shortcode
add_shortcode('pavideo_thumb','pavideo_get_thumbnails_and_pagination');
```

And it works just fine! :)